# Sling: Best way to get children resources, ordered

Tags: jcr, sling

**The Situation**

You're inside of a Java class, running in a Sling environment. You have a Resource instance. It has ~400 children. You want to get the 100 with the most recent date property "myDate."

**The requirement**

You MUST have actual Resource objects to operate on when you're done - not Node objects

**The preference**

You would PREFER not to write a comparator and compare all 400 objects in application server heap memory.

**How would you solve this?**

You could do an SQL 2 query... But that seems like a lot of effort and processing in order to meet the requirement of operating on Resource objects.

- Get A QueryManager instance
- Create and execute a query
- Convert the Node(s) in the result, back to a Resources, by resolving each and every one with ResourceResolver.resolve(node.getPath())

Oof that seems rough.

You could just resource.listChildren() to get ALL resources into heap memory, and then use Java Collections API and a comparator to sort them... But now you're processing all these data in application server memory and also having to write your own sorting logic. This violates the preference stated at the beginning.

Anybody know any fancy solutions?

If there was a way for SQL 2 queries to return Resource objects instead of Nodes, that would be nice. Or, if there was a way to specify criteria or ordering instructions inside the listChildren() method of Resource, that would be nice. What do people do in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Sling ResourceResolver has a method for this:

```
findResources(@Nonnull String query, String language)
```

It returns an iterator over resources. Ordering can be determined with the ORDER BY clause of the JCR-SQL2 language.